# Tree building infinite recursion detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, recursion, tree

I am working on `JQuery` mechanism that is building tree, it has to be as fast as possible. Volume of data is quite large so master record column is used to be able to 'grab' all relevant nodes in one select from webSQL db.
Whole mechanism but one part is done, when assembling tree it must check that there is no infinite recursion being created. What mechanism does at the moment if Record A is Master and Parent of record B, and Record B is Master and Parent of record A then structure like `A.Children[0] = B` and `B.Children[0] = A` is being built. It all would work fine, but it has do be knockout.js bound and displayed as expandable list to users, which results in overflow when trying to display the tree.
Requirement is to detect such loops and do not create tree relationships.

Mechanism that would check if item is already in the tree I came up is:

```
function InTree(master, item) {
    return $.inArray(item, $.map(master, function recurs(n) {
        return ($.isArray(n) ? $.map(n, recurs) : n);
    })) != -1;
}

if(!InTree(tree, record))
{
//attach 
} else {
// get next record
}
```

**Is there anything faster than `InTree()` function that would get me if item is in the tree?**

Whole tree building algorithm is below (not that I think it is relevant but rather to avoid the comments 'show the code')

```
$(document).on('OnPreQuery', onTheMove.PageDataRoles, function (e, options) {
    var isChildAttachmentQueued = true;
    var knockoutContextName = options.knockoutContextName;
    if (TreeEnabled(knockoutContextName)) {
        var isModelReadyToAttachChildren = function () {
            var isReady = false;
            if (PageObj[knockoutContextName] != undefined) {
                isReady = (PageObj[knockoutContextName]().length > 0) && isChildAttachmentQueued;
            }

            return isReady;
        };
        var businessComponent = eval(knockoutContextName);
            var treeSettings = businessComponent.Tree;
            treeSettings.knockoutContextName = knockoutContextName;
            $(businessComponent).on('OnPreUIUpdate', function (e, options) {
                if (isModelReadyToAttachChildren()) {
                    getChildrenForMasterRecordList({
                        parentTable: businessComponent.primaryTableName,
                        knockoutContextName: treeSettings.knockoutContextName,
                        parentIdColumn: treeSettings.ParentIdColumn,
                        masterIdColumn: treeSettings.MasterIdColumn
                    });
                    isChildAttachmentQueued = false;
                }
            });
    }
});

function TreeEnabled(knockoutContextName) {
    var isTreeEnabled = false;
    try {
        eval(knockoutContextName);
    } catch (e) {
        return isTreeEnabled;
    }
    var treeSettings = eval(knockoutContextName).Tree;
    if (treeSettings && treeSettings.IncludeChildren) {
        isTreeEnabled = true;
    }

    return isTreeEnabled;
}

function ComposeRecordsToTreeStructure(results, tableArray, columnArray, options) {
    if (results.rows.length > 0) {
        if (options.parentLayerIdList == undefined) {
            options.parentLayerIdList = options.masterIdList;
        }

        if (options.orphans == undefined) {
            options.orphans = [];
        }
        var knockoutContextName = options.knockoutContextName;
        var childRecordIdArray = [];
        if (options.runningOnOrphans) {
            if (options.orphans.length > 0) {
                for (var j = 0; j < options.orphans.length; j++) {
                    var rowRecord = options.orphans[j];
                    var rowRecordParentId = rowRecord[options.parentIdColumn];
                    var result = EstablishParentChildConnectionOnAlreadyProcessedNodes(rowRecord, rowRecordParentId, options.parentLayerIdList, knockoutContextName, childRecordIdArray, options);
                    if (result.hasEstablishedConnection) {
                        childRecordIdArray = result.childRecordIdArray;
                    }
                }

                options.orphans = $.grep(options.orphans, function (item) {
                    return $.inArray(item['Id'], childRecordIdArray) == -1;
                });
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                var rowRecord = results.rows.item(i);
                var rowRecordParentId = rowRecord[options.parentIdColumn];
                if (rowRecord[options.parentIdColumn] == '' || rowRecord[options.masterIdColumn] == '' || rowRecord[options.masterIdColumn] == rowRecord['Id']) {
                    rowRecord.isInvalid = true;
                } else if ($.inArray(rowRecord['Id'], options.masterIdList) != -1) {
                    masterRecordClone = $.grep(PageObj[knockoutContextName](), function (item) { return item.Fields.Id() == rowRecord['Id'] })[0];
                    if (masterRecordClone != undefined && masterRecordClone.Children) {
                        rowRecord.Children = masterRecordClone.Children;
                     }
                }

                if (rowRecord.isInvalid == true) {
                    if (rowRecord[options.masterIdColumn] != rowRecord['Id']) {
                        var result = EstablishParentChildConnection(rowRecord, rowRecord[options.masterIdColumn], options.parentLayerIdList, knockoutContextName, childRecordIdArray, options);
                        if (result.hasEstablishedConnection) {
                            childRecordIdArray = result.childRecordIdArray;
                            EstablishParentChildConnectionOnAlreadyProcessedNodes(rowRecord, rowRecordParentId, options.parentLayerIdList, knockoutContextName, childRecordIdArray, options);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    var result = EstablishParentChildConnectionOnAlreadyProcessedNodes(rowRecord, rowRecordParentId, options.parentLayerIdList, knockoutContextName, childRecordIdArray, options);
                    if (result.hasEstablishedConnection) {
                        childRecordIdArray = result.childRecordIdArray;
                    } else {
                        var recordObject = AddIsExpandedProperty(rowRecord);
                        options.orphans.push(recordObject);
                        options.runningOnOrphans = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (options.orphans.length > 0 && childRecordIdArray.length > 0) {
            options.parentLayerIdList = childRecordIdArray;
            ComposeRecordsToTreeStructure(results, tableArray, columnArray, options);
        }
    }

    onTheMove.seleniumHelper.markPageAsLoaded();
}

function EstablishParentChildConnectionOnAlreadyProcessedNodes(rowRecord, rowRecordParentId, parentLayerIdList, knockoutContextName, childRecordIdArray, options) {
    var result = EstablishParentChildConnection(rowRecord, rowRecordParentId, parentLayerIdList, knockoutContextName, childRecordIdArray);
    if (result.hasEstablishedConnection) {
        childRecordIdArray = result.childRecordIdArray;
    } else {
        var result = EstablishParentChildConnection(rowRecord, rowRecordParentId, childRecordIdArray, knockoutContextName, childRecordIdArray);
        if (result.hasEstablishedConnection) {
            childRecordIdArray = result.childRecordIdArray;
        } else {
            var matchingOrphans = $.grep(options.orphans, function (item) {
                return item['Id'] == rowRecordParentId;
            });
            if (matchingOrphans.length > 0) {
                AttachPassedChildRecord(rowRecord, matchingOrphans);
                var result = {
                    hasEstablishedConnection: true
                };
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        childRecordIdArray: childRecordIdArray,
        hasEstablishedConnection: result.hasEstablishedConnection
    };
}

function EstablishParentChildConnection(rowRecord, rowRecordParentId, parentLayerIdList, knockoutContextName, childRecordIdArray) {
    var hasEstablishedConnection = false;
    var parentPosition = $.inArray(rowRecordParentId, parentLayerIdList);
    if (parentPosition != -1) {
        AttachChildRecordsToParents(rowRecord, parentLayerIdList[parentPosition], knockoutContextName);
        childRecordIdArray = AddChildRecordsToNextParentList(rowRecord, childRecordIdArray);
        childRecordIdArray.push(rowRecord['Id']);
        hasEstablishedConnection = true;
    }

    return {
        childRecordIdArray: childRecordIdArray,
        hasEstablishedConnection: hasEstablishedConnection
    };
}

function AddChildRecordsToNextParentList(childRecord, childRecordIdArray) {
    if (childRecord.Children != undefined) {
        for (var i = 0; i < childRecord.Children.length; i++) {
            childRecordIdArray.push(childRecord.Children[i]['Id']);
            if (childRecord.Children[i].Children != undefined) {
                AddChildRecordsToNextParentList(childRecord.Children[i], childRecordIdArray);
            }
        }
    }

    return childRecordIdArray;
}

function RowsToListDataStructure(results) {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
        array.push(results.rows.item(i));
    }

    return array;
}

function AttachChildRecordsToParents(recordRow, id, knockoutContextName) {
    var childTreeOptions = {
        id: id,
        knockoutContextName: knockoutContextName,
        results: []
    };
    findObjectsInChildTreeById(childTreeOptions);
    if (childTreeOptions.results.length > 0) {
        AttachPassedChildRecord(recordRow, childTreeOptions.results);
    }
}

function AttachPassedChildRecord(recordObject, pageObjParentResults) {
    for (var i = 0; i < pageObjParentResults.length; i++) {
        if (pageObjParentResults[i].Children == undefined) {
            pageObjParentResults[i].Children = [];
        }
        if ($.grep(pageObjParentResults[i].Children, function (children) {
            return children['Id'] == recordObject['Id'];
        }).length == 0) {
            recordObject = AddIsExpandedProperty(recordObject);
            pageObjParentResults[i].Children.push(recordObject);
        }
    }
}

function AddIsExpandedProperty(recordObject) {
    recordObject.IsExpanded = ko.observable(false);
    return recordObject;
}

function findObjectsInChildTreeById(options) {
    if (options.item == undefined) {
        if (typeof PageObj[options.knockoutContextName] != 'undefined') {
            for (var item in PageObj[options.knockoutContextName]()) {
                findObjectsInChildTreeById({
                    item: PageObj[options.knockoutContextName]()[item],
                    id: options.id,
                    results: options.results
                });
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (typeof options.item.Fields != 'undefined') {
            if (options.item.Fields['Id']() == options.id)
                options.results.push(options.item);
        } else {
            if (options.item['Id'] == options.id)
                options.results.push(options.item);
        }

        if (options.item.Children != undefined) {
            for (var item in options.item.Children) {
                findObjectsInChildTreeById({
                    item: options.item.Children[item],
                    id: options.id,
                    results: options.results
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

function getChildrenForMasterRecordList(options) {
    var parentTable = options.parentTable,
        masterIdColumn = options.masterIdColumn,
        parentIdColumn = options.parentIdColumn,
        knockoutContextName = options.knockoutContextName,
        masterIds = getParentIdsAndMastersOfParentsFromPageObj(knockoutContextName, masterIdColumn);
    for (var item in PageObj[options.knockoutContextName]()) {
        AddIsExpandedProperty(PageObj[knockoutContextName]()[item]);
    }

    var dbManager = new OnTheMoveDatabaseManager();
    dbManager.queryDatabase({
        statement: {
            Tables: [{
                Alias: parentTable,
                JoinSpec: null,
                JoinType: "",
                Name: parentTable
            }, {
                Alias: "Record",
                JoinSpec: "Record.Id = " + parentTable + ".Id",
                JoinType: "INNER",
                Name: "Record"
            }],
            WhereClause: parentTable + "." + masterIdColumn + " IN ('" + masterIds.join("','") + "') AND Record.RecordType ='" + parentTable + "'",
            SelectFields: [{
                IsAggregate: false,
                Name: "*"
            }],
            DisablePaging: true,
            OrderClause: "Record.Id"
        },
        knockoutContextName: knockoutContextName,
        isObservable: false,
        masterIdColumn: masterIdColumn,
        masterIdList: masterIds,
        parentIdColumn: parentIdColumn,
        parentTable: options.parentTable,
        success: function (results, tableArray, columnArray, options) {
            ComposeRecordsToTreeStructure(results, tableArray, columnArray, options);
        }
    });
}

function getParentIdsAndMastersOfParentsFromPageObj(knockoutContextName, masterColumnName) {
    var list = [];
    if (typeof PageObj[knockoutContextName] != 'undefined') {
        for (var item in PageObj[knockoutContextName]()) {
            if ($.inArray(PageObj[knockoutContextName]()[item].Fields['Id'](), list) == -1) {
                list.push(PageObj[knockoutContextName]()[item].Fields['Id']());
            }
            if (PageObj[knockoutContextName]()[item].Fields[masterColumnName]() != '' && $.inArray(PageObj[knockoutContextName]()[item].Fields[masterColumnName](), list) == -1) {
                list.push(PageObj[knockoutContextName]()[item].Fields[masterColumnName]());
             }
        }
    }

    return list
}

function InTree(master, item) {
    return $.inArray(item, $.map(master, function recurs(n) {
        return ($.isArray(n) ? $.map(n, recurs) : n);
    })) != -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your circumstances. if you're able to run code on add/creation of the tree you may simply create a node id array and do a check like

```
if(allNodes[searchKey])
   //etc
```

This is a very specific solution of course but technically it'd be as fast as it could possibly be.